# Why can i call pg_dump but not pg_start_backup directly in my batch file?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, backup, psql

I'm writing a batch file for doing incremental backups of a cluster of Postgres Databases.

For doing a full backup, i am using pg_dump and pg_dump_all, which works no problem if i for example do it like this:

```
@echo off && pushd "%~dp0"
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGPORT=5432
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=SOMEPSW
set BACKUPDIR=C:\some\path
set CURRENTDATE=%CURRENTDATE:~0,14%
set BACKUPPATH=%BACKUPDIR%\%CURRENTDATE%

pg_dumpall -r -f %BACKUPPATH%\users.backup <---- THIS IS THE LINE I WANT TO REPLACE

popd
pause
exit /b %RETURNCODE%
```

(I have tried shaving down the example, to make it quick and easy to read, let my know if anything is unclear).

As far as i have understood, i can't use pg_dump and pg_dumpall for incremental backups, so i want to use pg_start_backup and pg_stop_backup as part of my incremental script, and inbetween create zip and move the Data folder.

My issue right now is that i can't call either of them, because they are not recognized commands.

I have tried calling them in the following ways:

1.

```
pg_start_backup('label', false, false);
```

This does not work because pg_start_backup is not recognized as an internal or external command.

2.

```
SELECT pg_start_backup('label', false, false);
```

This does not work because SELECT is not recognized as an internal or external command.

3.

```
psql -h %PGHOST% -p %PGPORT% -U %PGUSER% -d %DATABASES% -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('label', false, false);"
psql -h %PGHOST% -p %PGPORT% -U %PGUSER% -d %DATABASES% -c "SELECT * FROM pg_stop_backup(false, true);"
```

This does not work, because it starts the backup in one context, and tries to stop it in another, hence throwing this error: "ERROR:  non-exclusive backup is not in progress".

4.

```
psql -h %DB_HOST% -p %DB_PORT% -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME% -f test.sql
```

This DOES work, but i need to put some batch logic between pg_start_backup and pg_stop_backup, and i don't want to have several sql files i need to call.

What is causing my issues, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that pg_dump and pg_dumpall are .exe files in the bin folder. Guess that explains why i can call them directly.

But i'm still confused as to how i'm supposed to call pg_start_backup() and pg_stop_backup() then.